# Microsoft Web Farm 2.0 and URL Rewrite: How to route port 80 traffic to port 591?

Tags: rewrite, web-farm

I have the Controller and the Primary server on the same computer.  I would like to URL Rewrite inbound port 80 traffic bound for the controller to port 591 on the web farm.

What URL Rewrite rule could I use to redirect traffic from port 80 to port 591?  Or, is there some manual/blog out there that instructs how to put both the Controller and the Primary on the same server?

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work, but backwards.  I had the Cisco router NAT traffic from the outside port 80 to the inside port 591 going to the Controller.  Then I had the Controller route traffic to the Primary and Secondary on port 80, one of which happened to be on the same machine.  It got around the ASP.NET MVC 3 routing issues I was having too.

Only problem is it keeps resetting the servers and I get either 500 or 404 errors.  Everything works for a day after I restart, but a day later it fails.